# Converting a Javascript energy calculator to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code for an energy calculator in Javascript but I am looking to write it in jQuery so I can have some cool effects like show / hide, etc.

Here is the original Javascript code.

```
function validateForm(){
  hours_used = document.getElementById('hours').value;
  //validation
  if(hours_used < 1 || isNaN(hours_used) || hours_used == ""){
    alert('Please enter a valid number for hours used per day');
    document.getElementById('hours').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('hours').focus();
    return false;
  }else if (hours_used > 24){
    alert('There is only 24 hours in a day');
    document.getElementById('hours').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('hours').focus();
    return false;
  }else{
    return getEnergyCosts();
  }
} //end validateForm function
//getEnergyCosts function
//calculates energy costs for appliance
//based on hours used per day
function getEnergyCosts(){
  watts = document.getElementById('appliance').value;
  hours_used = document.getElementById('hours').value;
  //cost per kilowatt divide by 100 to get pence figure
  var cpk = 14.5/100;
  //divide watts by 1000 to get kw
  var kilowatt = watts / 1000;
  kw_used = hours_used * kilowatt;
  //calculate costs
  cost_per_day = kw_used * cpk;
  cost_per_week = cost_per_day * 7;
  cost_per_month = cost_per_week * 4;
  cost_per_year = cost_per_month * 12;
  document.getElementById('kilowatts_used').innerHTML = kw_used.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('cost_day').innerHTML = "£"+cost_per_day.toFixed(2)+"p";
  document.getElementById('cost_week').innerHTML = "£"+cost_per_week.toFixed(2)+"p";
  document.getElementById('cost_month').innerHTML = "£"+cost_per_month.toFixed(2)+"p";
  document.getElementById('cost_year').innerHTML = "£"+cost_per_year.toFixed(2)+"p";
  //return false to stop form reloading
  return false;
}
function reset_form(){
  //resets variables when reset button is clicked
  //possibly don't need this
  watts = 0;
  kw_used = 0;
  cost_per_day = 0;
  cost_per_week = 0;
  cost_per_month = 0;
  cost_per_year = 0;
  document.getElementById('kilowatts_used').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_day').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_week').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_month').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_year').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Here's what I have so far in jQuery, unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with creating functions (or plugins as this basically will be a plugin) in jQuery, so it does not work as it should. The form validation part seems to work, i.e. if I leave the hours text box black or don't input a number, it returns the alert box but the `getEnergyCosts` function does not work as it should. The div which wraps around the results will not show and the form refreshes with the value of the selected item in the URL. Basically I don't think the `getEnergyCosts` function is being run.

The only error I seem to be getting is a reference error invalid left-hand side at this line:

```
   $('#kilowatts_used').html() = kw_used.toFixed(2);
```

Can anyone give me some tips as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
jQuery.fn.validateForm = function() {
  var hours_used = parseInt($('#hours').val());
  //validation
  if(hours_used < 1 || isNaN(hours_used) || hours_used == ""){
    alert('Please enter a valid number for hours used per day');
    document.getElementById('hours').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('hours').focus();
    return false;
  }else if (hours_used > 24){
    alert('There is only 24 hours in a day');
    document.getElementById('hours').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('hours').focus();
  }else{
    return $(this).getEnergyCosts();
  }
} //end validateForm function
//getEnergyCosts function
//calculates energy costs for appliance
//based on hours used per day
jQuery.fn.getEnergyCosts = function() {
  var watts = parseInt($('#appliance').val());
  var hours_used = parseInt($('#hours').val());
  //cost per kilowatt divide by 100 to get pence figure
  var cpk = 14.5/100;
  //divide watts by 1000 to get kw
  var kilowatt = watts / 1000;
  kw_used = hours_used * kilowatt;
  //calculate costs
  cost_per_day = kw_used * cpk;
  cost_per_week = cost_per_day * 7;
  cost_per_month = cost_per_week * 4;
  cost_per_year = cost_per_month * 12;
  $('#kilowatts_used').html() = kw_used.toFixed(2);
  $('#cost_day').html() = "£"+cost_per_day.toFixed(2)+"p";
  $('#cost_week').html() = "£"+cost_per_week.toFixed(2)+"p";
  $('#cost_month').html() = "£"+cost_per_month.toFixed(2)+"p";
  $('#cost_year').html() = "£"+cost_per_year.toFixed(2)+"p";
  //return false to stop from reloading
  $('#results').show(fast);
}
jQuery.fn.reset_form = function() {
  //resets variables when reset button is clicked
  //possibly don't need this
  watts = 0;
  kw_used = 0;
  cost_per_day = 0;
  cost_per_week = 0;
  cost_per_month = 0;
  cost_per_year = 0;
  document.getElementById('kilowatts_used').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_day').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_week').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_month').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('cost_year').innerHTML = "";
}
```

This is what I have in the HTML file to call the jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#results').hide();
    $('.submit').click(function(){
      $(this).validateForm();
      return false;
    });
    $('.reset').click(function(){
      reset_form();
      $('#results').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

For reference this is the HTML code for the form:

```
<div id="energy-calculator">
  <form id="e-calc">
    <div class="element">
      <label for="appliance">Select an appliance</label>
      <select name="appliance" id="appliance" tabindex="1">
        <option value="2000">Oven</option>
        <option value="1100">Microwave</option>
        <option value="1500">Portable Heater</option>
        <option value="200">Desktop Computer</option>
        <option value="40">Laptop Computer</option>
        <option value="150">Games Consoles (PS3 / X Box)</option>
        <option value="16">Games Console (Wii)</option>
        <option value="70">Television 19 inch</option>
        <option value="150">Television 25 inch</option>
        <option value="450">Hoover</option>
        <option value="500">Fridge/Freezer</option>
        <option value="3500">Tumble Dryer</option>
        <option value="700">Washing Machine</option>
        <option value="1350">Dishwasher</option>
        <option value="11">Energy Saving Light Bulb</option>
        <option value="23">Digital TV Box</option>
        <option value="1000">Hair Dryer</option>
        <option value="123">Straighteners</option>
        <option value="35">Stereo System</option>
        <option value="35">DVD Player</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <label for="hours">How many hours on average do you use the appliance per day?</label>
      <input type="text" id="hours" tabindex="2" size="2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <input type="submit" value="Get Costs" class="submit" tabindex="3"/>
    </div>
    <!-- results -->
    <div id="results">
      <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Kilowatts used per day:</span>
        <div id="kilowatts_used" class="results_box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Total cost per day is:</span>
        <div id="cost_day" class="results_box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Total cost per week is:</span>
        <div id="cost_week" class="results_box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Total cost per month is:</span>
        <div id="cost_month" class="results_box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <span class="label">Total cost per year is:</span>
        <div id="cost_year" class="results_box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" class="reset" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Rule number 1: If it works in plain JavaScript, do NOT change it to jQuery. "If it's not broken, don't fix it."

Answer (score 2):

`.html` is a function where you're expected to pass a value, you don't assign to it.

```
$('#kilowatts_used').html(kw_used.toFixed(2));
```

If you're just setting the text, and not appending actual HTML content, I would advise you to use `.text` instead:

```
$('#kilowatts_used').text(kw_used.toFixed(2));
```

Furthermore, jQuery sits on top of JavaScript. You don't have to convert your existing code to use more jQuery, in order to utilize jQuery functions for showing and hiding. You can add jQuery functions at your convenience, regardless of how the rest of the script is written.

It is only in the specific scenarios when you want to utilize a jQuery function that you need to make sure that you're working with a jQuery object and not directly with a DOM node. So you could very well write code like:

```
document.getElementById('kilowatts_used').innerHTML = 'xxx';
$('#kilowatts_used').show();
```

Or:

```
var kw_used = document.getElementById('kilowatts_used');
kw_used.innerHTML = 'xxx';
$(kw_used).show();
```